# Why error 500 raise when I use domain.com instead of domain.com/en/ in Django i18n?

Tags: django, django-i18n

I added a second language to my `Django` project and when in `Debug=False` mode I enter `domain.com` I get `ERROR 500` but `domain.com/en/` works perfectly.
In `Debug=True` is no error.

My `i18n` settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('fa', _('Persian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    )
```

My template:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}                         
<div class="languages">
    <ul class="languages">
    {% for language in languages %}
        <li class="languages">
        <a href="/{{ language.code }}/" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} class='selected'{% endif %}>{{ language.name_local }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The error I get in my browser and when I test in local with Django development server is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

And the errors I get from my production nginx server:

> [17/Sep/2020:07:15:32] GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 4994 "-"

> [17/Sep/2020:07:15:33] GET /static/logo/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0

- the favicon is available in this address: `/static/logo/favicon.ico`

Comment: can you please send the error details?

Comment: When the Debug is True, there is no error and when the debug is False it says "500 Internal Server Error" and I don't know how to find more details about 500 error. This situation, in local (Django development server) and on my production server (nginx and uwsgi) are the same.

Comment: When the Debug is True, there is no error and when the debug is False it says "500 Internal Server Error" and I don't know how to find more details about 500 error. This situation, in local (Django development server) and on my production server (nginx and uwsgi) are the same.

Comment: Are you logging the detail of the error? If so, please add the logs of the error in your question.

Comment: @MKJ I've added the error logs.

Comment: @MKJ I've added the error logs.